# Does Lao (or Thai) have any "verbalizer" morphemes?

Tags: morphosyntax, lao, derivation, morphemes, nominals

I know of at least two morphemes in lao which are nominalizers that can convert lexical verbs or adjectives into nouns: [ການ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%BA%81%E0%BA%B2%E0%BA%99#Lao) and [ຄວາມ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%BA%84%E0%BA%A7%E0%BA%B2%E0%BA%A1).

What I'm wondering is whether there are any counterparts which serve the complementary function, that of converting lexical nouns into verbs?